# App icon not appearing in app switcher in ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appicon

I have recently developed a set of icons for my ios app using https://makeappicon.com. This provides a folder of appropriately sized images. I then have dragged each of these images into the appropriate slot in the AppIcon section in Assets.xcassets. The icon shows up fine in on my phone screen but not in the app switcher (see circled in image). There are no errors showing.

[image]

I have: 
- Cleaned build folder and rebuilt
- I have restarted my iPhone
- I have manually placed all the images in the slots
- I have also tried replacing the original AppIcon folder with the one provided by make appicon

All to no effect. Be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, answering my own question here. Hopefully it may help anyone who has same issue. I ended up deleting the app and restarting. The icon in the app switcher now appears.

Comment: Using Simulator, I had to quit it and restart—deleting the app and reinstalling still didn't cause the app icon to show for me.

Answer (score 25):

**Uninstall App** → **Restart Device** → **Install App**

Just putting here for the sake of working answer !
As @cobberboy has mentioned in comment, doing above works - verified

Comment: Just restarting the device did the trick for me

Comment: Wow, i lost many hours with this bug. Your answer saved me! :D

Comment: Restarting the device fixes it!

Comment: Just restarting the device, it works!

Answer (score 13):

I have been trying to figure out this issue, as I multiple times changed the icons removed the build, took new builds etc, but the app switcher icon was the default icon.

I have tried the app on a new phone and the desired icon was showing. So my guess is that the app switcher, (also apple watch OS's app switcher) has some sort of hardcore cache machanism.

If anyone coming from Google facing this issue, not sure how to flush this cache, but you can go ahead and ship your app, as this cache is only on your device.

Good luck!

Comment: If you uninstall the app, restart your device, and then install the app again, the icon shows up.

Comment: For me (iOS 14.3 - Simulator 12.3) just restarting the simulator was enough

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have provided icons for all sizes, deploy, then restart the device to clear any caches.